# Check multiple files exist for each folders

Tags: python

I am looking for the way to print out the file that not exist in directories.

So far I could do

```
QA_files_pattern = '*QA.xlsx'
EP_files_pattern = '*EP.xlsx'
AD_files_pattern = '*AD.xlsx'

filelist = [QA_files_pattern,EP_files_pattern,AD_files_pattern]

path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())


for (path, dir, files) in os.walk(path): # Get all files in current file's path
    for a_file in filelist:
    
        if fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(path), a_file):
            print(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(path), a_file))
        else:
            print("missing"+path+a_file)
```

The problem in this way is that it checks whether the files pattern exist not only the folders I want to look for but also every root it enters to reach to folder I want to look for.

Will there be a way to make it search just the end path?

EDIT: I cannot specify how many subfolders there will be, but I am sure the files are only contained at the end folders and the common name for end folder is 'QS'

Comment: what folders do you want to inspect? do you have a list of their names or a pattern?

Comment: @freude the common folder name is QS

Comment: maybe you'll find the `pathlib` library helpful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I was able to solve for my own question, which was much simpler way than I expected

```
QA_files_pattern = '*QA.xlsx'
EP_files_pattern = '*EP.xlsx'
AD_files_pattern = '*AD.xlsx'

filelist = [QA_files_pattern,EP_files_pattern,AD_files_pattern]

path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())

for (path, dir, files) in os.walk(path): # Get all files in current file's path
    if "QS" in path:
        for a_file in filelist:
            if fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(path), a_file):
                print(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(path), a_file))
            else:
                print("missing"+path+a_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your path so that it is explicitly on the file path you desire.

Right now you are setting the path on the current directory, which I believe is the root.

```
path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
```

You could make it a path that is explicity to limit it

```
path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
extended_path= os.path.join(path, "specific_directory", "subdirectory", "etc")
```

And then sub in the extended_path

```
for (extended_path, dir, files) in os.walk(extended_path): # Get all files in current file's path
    for a_file in filelist:
    
        if fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(extended_path), a_file):
            print(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(extended_path), a_file))
        else:
            print("missing"+extended_path+a_file)
```

Comment: I tried to put wildcard for the extended_path like `extended_path= os.path.join(path, "*","*","QS*")`  but it does not work :(

Comment: Apologies, I believe `os.path.join()` needs to be explicit and I do not believe you can use wild cards in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) recursively for something like:

```
from glob import glob
from os import path

QA = "*QA.xlsx"
EP = "*EP.xlsx"
AD = "*AD.xlsx"

base_path = "/base/path/**/*" # change /base/path to the dir you want to check

for d in glob(base_path, recursive=1): # get all files/dirs recursively inside base_path
    if path.isdir(d): # If is a dir
        to_match = {"QA":glob(f"{d}/{QA}"), "EP":glob(f"{d}/{EP}"), "AD":glob(f"{d}/{AD}")}
        for k, v in to_match.items():
            if not v:
                print(f"Dir '{d}' Missing {k}")
```

Comment: how about if the base_path is not specified? so there could be 2 or 5 or 10 subfolders to reach to the folder that contains files

Comment: You need a pattern to make this work, try to find one, perhaps in the folder names.